# Select values based on distance and time

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to match the values of two table based on the following spatial and time conditions:

- Two hour time interval
- min(dist), max dist 20km

I can solve the problem using for loops but since the tables' dimension are 3million * 10, 100 000 * 13 it takes too long to complete.

Do you have any suggestion? I post below a practical example and the desired outpu. Thank you.

**Example**

```
DT1 <- data.table(
Date = as.POSIXct(c("2005-01-05 10:40:00", "2005-01-06 10:40:00", "2005-01-07 10:40:00", "2005-01-08 10:40:00", "2005-01-09 10:40:00", "2005-01-10 10:40:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %T", tz = "GMT"), 
Lat = c(rep(50, 3), 35.44, 25.44, 15.44), 
Lon = c(rep(-50, 3), -10.44, -20.44, -30.44), 
Other.col = sample(LETTERS, 6))

DT2 <- data.table(
Date = as.POSIXct(c("2011-01-01 10:40:00", "2005-01-05 11:40:00", "2005-01-09 08:59:00", "2005-01-09 09:18:00", "2005-01-10 08:59:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %T", tz = "GMT"), 
Lat = c(35.44, 1, 25.54, 25.43, 15.46), 
Lon = c(-10.44, 1, -20.66, -20.42, -30.13),
Quality = c("h", "f", "n", "z", "l"))

DT1
                  Date   Lat    Lon Other.col
1: 2005-01-05 10:40:00 50.00 -50.00         E
2: 2005-01-06 10:40:00 50.00 -50.00         C
3: 2005-01-07 10:40:00 50.00 -50.00         O
4: 2005-01-08 10:40:00 35.44 -10.44         Z
5: 2005-01-09 10:40:00 25.44 -20.44         T
6: 2005-01-10 10:40:00 15.44 -30.44         S

DT2
                  Date   Lat    Lon Quality
1: 2011-01-01 10:40:00 35.44 -10.44       h
2: 2005-01-05 11:40:00  1.00   1.00       f
3: 2005-01-09 08:59:00 25.54 -20.66       n
4: 2005-01-09 09:18:00 25.43 -20.42       z
5: 2005-01-10 08:59:00 15.46 -30.13       l

Output
                  Date   Lat    Lon Other.col V2
1: 2005-01-05 10:40:00 50.00 -50.00         E NA
2: 2005-01-06 10:40:00 50.00 -50.00         C NA
3: 2005-01-07 10:40:00 50.00 -50.00         O NA
4: 2005-01-08 10:40:00 35.44 -10.44         Z NA
5: 2005-01-09 10:40:00 25.44 -20.44         T  z
6: 2005-01-10 10:40:00 15.44 -30.44         S  l
```

Comment: For your specific example you could do `DT1[DT2, V2 := i.Quality, on = c(Date = "Date"), roll = -2*60*60]` but it's not very clear to me the "2 hours" interval, does it mean both ways? Also, the distance part will be more difficult as you need to run a complicated formula for each match. I think you could solve the 2 hours interval first and then run the formula on the subset in a vectorized way. But as it stands now, your examples seem to be too simplified. What happens for instance if two values in `DT2` satisfy the condition for the same value in `DT1`?

Comment: The two hours interval is indeed both ways. If two values in `DT2` satisfy the condition in `DT1` the closest point is chosen.